# Automatically verify a user email when connecting using an AuthProvider in Firebase without using the sendEmailVerification method?

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

I have implemented buttons to connect with GitHub, Twitter and Facebook on my application using Firebase `AuthProvider`. Even though it works and the users are registered and logged in, there email address is considered as not verified. Because they connect using an already existing account on another platform I assume that their email is already verified by these platform so I'd like to skip the `sendEmailVerification()` phase and automatically consider their email to be verified. How can I do that in Angular ?

Here is how I implemented the sign in process :

```js
async loginWithSocial(social: string) {
    try {
        let provider = null;
        if (social === "github") {
            provider = new firebase.auth.GithubAuthProvider();
        } else if (social === "twitter") {
            provider = new firebase.auth.TwitterAuthProvider();
        } else if (social === "facebook") {
            provider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();
        }
        const result = await firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider);
        const credential = result.credential;
        const user = await this.auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
        await this.router.navigate(["/", "home"]);
    } catch (error) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not all platforms verify all email addresses. For those that do (Google for @gmail.com, Facebook for @facebook.com, etc), Firebase Authentication reflects that in the verification state in the user profile.

If you want to have looser requirements around this for you app, you can [set the `emailVerified` flag from a trusted environment using the Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#update_a_user). This cannot be done from the client-side SDKs, as that would allow any user to set their own flags.